# Sequence of Young tableaux

Tags: tables

I am doing my semester thesis, but I have no idea how to do Young tableaux in latex.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. You have been here for quite some time now. So please give us with a MWE to start with `(-1)`. Moreover, if you found the answers for your past questions helpful, consider accepting them by clicking the `tick-mark` on the top-left corner near the vote button of the answer. Moreover, you have been given with several examples for your past question to achieve something close to this.

Comment: There are several packages dedicated to Young tableaux available. Which of them are you using?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a just-do-it-for-me question

Comment: @Down-voters: Please don't downvote below a score of -1, even if the question in its current form needs some improvement. A score of -1 is enough to show that the question needs work, anything below that is of no use. Also, if you downvote or vote to close, please leave a comment explaining why you did so, but wait at least 24 hours after asking the OP for improvements to the question before voting to close.

Comment: use the package `\usepackage{ytableau}`. The documentation is very complete.

Answer (score 7):

For empty tableaux the `ytableau` package provides `\ydiagram`; it is thought for “skewed tableaux”, but works well also in this case.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\usepackage{ytableau}

\newcommand{\tabgt}{\mathrel{\unrhd}}

\begin{document}

\[
\ytableausetup{aligntableaux=center}
\thickmuskip=12mu % wider in this context
\ydiagram{0+4}
\tabgt
\ydiagram{0+3,0+1}
\tabgt
\ydiagram{0+2,0+2}
\tabgt
\ydiagram{0+2,0+1,0+1}
\tabgt
\ydiagram{0+1,0+1,0+1,0+1}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

One out of many possible ways.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ytableau}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\begin{document}

\[\ytableausetup{aligntableaux=center}
    \begin{ytableau}
    ~               & ~ &    ~               & ~ \\
    \end{ytableau}~\unrhd~
    \begin{ytableau}
    ~               & ~ &    ~        \\       
    ~ & \none & \none\\
    \end{ytableau}~\unrhd~
    \begin{ytableau}
    ~               & ~         \\       
    ~ & ~\\
    \end{ytableau}~\unrhd~
    \begin{ytableau}
    ~               & ~         \\       
    ~ & \none \\
    ~ & \none \\
    \end{ytableau}~\unrhd~
    \begin{ytableau}
    ~ \\       
    ~\\
    ~\\
    ~\\
    \end{ytableau}
\]  
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course you can shorten this considerably.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[vcentermath]{youngtab}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}

\[  \yng(4)~\unrhd~\yng(3,1)~\unrhd~\yng(2,2)~\unrhd~\yng(2,1,1)~\unrhd~
\yng(1,1,1,1)\]  
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for the latter code

Comment: @JouleV I actually like the first one better since most likely the OP will eventually need to fill these tableaux with something, so I wanted to provide something that can easily be adopted to that case.

Comment: I think adding some text is also possible (and easy) with `youngtab`.

Comment: @JouleV Sure. There is another package, `young`, which is also useful and easy to use.